# Angular JS $modal creating detached DOM

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working on an Angular JS application which is in production. It is using the Angular JS version 1.0.8 and Angular UI Bootstrap 0.6

I have noticed that once I simply open and close a modal, I lose few mega bytes of memory. I suspected that to be a memory leak so here is how it looks with the three snapshot technique.

Load the page
Took Snapshot 1 
Open Modal
Took Snapshot 2
Close Modal
Took Snapshot 3

The summary view for objects between Snapshot 1 and 2 looks like this:

[image]

As far as my understanding goes, if we keep using this, we will continuously lose available memory and the He's Dead Jim comes up.

Here is how the code for the modal looks like:

```
        $scope.openCreateTicket = function () {
            $location.search('state', 'create');
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/ticketing/modals/CreateTicketModal.html',
                controller: 'CreateTicketModalCtrl',
                windowClass: 'modal-medium'
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('ticketAdded');
                $location.search('state', null);
            }, function () {
                $location.search('state', null);
            });
        };
```

I am continuously looking into resources but it is leading me no where, it would be great if the community can provide me with some insight..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seem that this problem [has been fixed](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1491) with angular-ui v0.11.